# UIAlertView for user to download another app

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I downloaded an app from app store and noticed that once I installed and opened the app, I got a UIAlertView suggesting that I download another app..

How can I achieve this? Are there any existing code that I can be directed towards?

Seems like a simple feature but I'd like to integrate it. Please see attachment[image]

Here is my edited code, but the 'Hello' button won't link anywhere.. What am I doing wrong?

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                  message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message."
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Hello", nil];
[message show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Hello"])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/islam/id667021108?mt=8&affId=1930871&ign-mpt=uo%3D4"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: you set no delegate... Below it says `self` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to make alertView, if you want to show the alert as first thing but this code  inside (ViewDidLoad) method

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"your title"
                      message:@"your message"
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Not now"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Download now"
                      , nil];
[alert show];
```

after viewDidLoad but this method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"here but your application link"]];
}else{

     }
}
```

//=================================================//

To know what's NSUserDefaults, I suggest to take a look the official doc.

And of course you can use it to fulfill your goal. You use a user default to store information about the current amount of runs in the app.

More or less like:

```
BOOL NotTheFirstTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     boolForKey:@"NotTheFirstTime"];
if(!NotTheFirstTime){
// Show the alert view
// Then set the first run flag
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"NotTheFirstTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

if that help you please make it the best question.

Comment: Ahhhh!! Thank you so much :) works wonders. Just another question - how do I enter something that says show this message after every X times user opens the app? I don't want the alert to show every single time because it will become annoying lol. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It **is** pretty simple:

1) Set up an `UIAlertView` as usual with the text and the button titles you like.

2) Set up the `UIAlertView`'s delegate and use this method to figure out which button was clicked (whether the user does or does not want to go to the App Store):

```
alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

3) If the user wants to go to the App Store, open up an App Store link:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"<#This is your App Store Link#>"]];
```